# How to fix Devexpress ASpxUploadControl control when pressing Add button in firefox?

Tags: devexpress

Hi
I'm using ASpxUploadControl from devexpress asp.net tools, 'Add' button was allowed and when I press it in Firefox4 I get this javascript error:

```
    this.fileInputSeparatorTemplateNode is undefined
    Source File: http://localhost:21390/DXR.axd?r=1_53
    Line: 370
```

But when using it on IE8 every thing is all right, any help with this ?

Answer (score 1):

which version of DX controls are you using?  I tried to reproduce the problem using the [ASPxUploadControl - Multi-File Upload](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/UploadControl/MultiFileUpload.aspx) demo (it is built using the latest, 10.2.8, release) and do not see this issue.  Please try to install the same version, perhaps it will help.

Comment: Firefox 4 and IE 9 are supported from DXperience 10.2.6.  You should install this version or a newer one to have this issue fixed.